# Replacing newlines with spaces for str columns through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, strip

Given an example dataframe with the 2nd and 3rd columns of free text, e.g.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lol = [[1,2,'abc','foo\nbar'], [3,1, 'def\nhaha', 'love it\n']]
>>> pd.DataFrame(lol)
   0  1          2          3
0  1  2        abc   foo\nbar
1  3  1  def\nhaha  love it\n
```

The goal is to replace the `\n` to  (whitespace) and strip the string in column 2 and 3 to achieve:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(lol)
   0  1         2        3
0  1  2       abc  foo bar
1  3  1  def haha  love it
```

**How to replace newlines with spaces for specific columns through pandas dataframe?**

I have tried this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lol = [[1,2,'abc','foo\nbar'], [3,1, 'def\nhaha', 'love it\n']]

>>> replace_and_strip = lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' ').strip()

>>> lol2 = [[replace_and_strip(col) if type(col) == str else col for col in list(row)] for idx, row in pd.DataFrame(lol).iterrows()]

>>> pd.DataFrame(lol2)
   0  1         2        3
0  1  2       abc  foo bar
1  3  1  def haha  love it
```

But there must be a better/simpler way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - first first and last strip and then replace `\n`:

```
df = df.replace({r'\s+$': '', r'^\s+': ''}, regex=True).replace(r'\n',  ' ', regex=True)
print (df)
   0  1         2        3
0  1  2       abc  foo bar
1  3  1  def haha  love it
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following two regex replace approach:

```
>>> df.replace({ r'\A\s+|\s+\Z': '', '\n' : ' '}, regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df
   0  1         2        3
0  1  2       abc  foo bar
1  3  1  def haha  love it
>>>
```

**Details**

- `'\A\s+|\s+\Z'` -> `''` will act like `strip()` removing all leading and trailing whitespace:

  - `\A\s+` - matches 1 or more whitespace symbols at the start of the string
  - `|` - or
  - `\s+\Z` - matches 1 or more whitespace symbols at the end of the string
- `'\n'` -> `' '` will replace any newline with a space.

Answer (score 1):

You can `select_dtypes` to select columns of type `object` and use `applymap` on those columns.

Because there is no `inplace` argument for these functions, this would be a workaround to make change to the dataframe:

```
strs = lol.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
lol[strs.columns] = strs
lol
#   0  1         2        3
#0  1  2       abc  foo bar
#1  3  1  def haha  love it
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other nice answers, this is a vectorized version of your initial idea:

```
columns = [2,3] 
df.iloc[:, columns] = [df.iloc[:,col].str.strip().str.replace('\n',' ') 
                       for col in columns]
```

---

Details:

```
In [49]: df.iloc[:, columns] = [df.iloc[:,col].str.strip().str.replace('\n',' ') 
                                 for col in columns]  

In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
   0  1        2         3
0  1  2      abc  def haha
1  3  1  foo bar   love it
```