# Is Pandas DataFrame.replace with regex dictionary not working, or am I making some mistake?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

MMWE:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'A': [0, 1, 2],
             'B': ['ba\nt', 'foo', 'bait'],
             'C': ['abc', 'ba\nr', 'xyz']}
        )
In [2]: df
Out[2]:     A   B       C
        0   0   ba\nt   abc
        1   1   foo     ba\nr
        2   2   bait    xyz

In [3]: df.replace(regex={'\n': '', 'foo': 'xyz'})  # Neither do r'\n' or '\\n' work.
Out[3]:     A   B       C
        0   0   ba\nt   abc
        1   1   xyz     ba\nr
        2   2   bait    xyz
```

Note that the MMWE is adapted from pandas docs on [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), and I can confirm that the example given in the docs works perfectly, provided the `df` doesn't have escaped characters.

Further note, answers using regex to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46522652/3765319) also do not work.

Expected:

```
Out[3]:     A   B      C
        0   0   bat    abc
        1   1   xyz    bar
        2   2   bait   xyz
```

---

Working:

```
In [4]: df.replace('\n', '', regex=True).replace('foo', 'xyz')
Out[4]:     A   B      C
        0   0   bat    abc
        1   1   xyz    bar
        2   2   bait   xyz
```

But, of course, that is not what I am looking for. Should I report this as a bug?

---

**EDIT**

Mystery deepens:

```
In [5]: df.replace(regex={'\n': '', r'^fo.$': 'xyz'})
Out[5]:     A   B       C
        0   0   ba\nt   abc
        1   1   xyz     ba\nr
        2   2   bait    xyz
```

It seems the issue is only with escaped characters.

---

**EDIT**

Version information:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.1.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.24.1
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked as expected.

Comment: `df.replace(regex={'\n': '', 'foo': 'xyz'})` works in my Python 3.6.

Comment: Hmmm... I am on Windows, what are you working on? Perhaps that is the issue. Let me check in Linux.

Comment: works just fine

Comment: Why would the OS make a difference? What is your Python and Pandas version?

Comment: @Kartik works fine on windows for me too. note that the original df is not modified unless you do it inplace. What pandas version is this?

Comment: It's most probably a bug then. I'm sure none of you tried it on Python 3.7.1 and Pandas 0.24.1, on Windows 10, right?

Comment: It is a version specific bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25266. Voted to close question.

Comment: on linux 3.7 & 3.6 python with pandas version 23 its works without any issues..