# Python convert JSON to CSV ignoring "\n"

Tags: python, json, csv

for my university project i have to collect some data from github using the API. I save the result of my api call into a json file and after that i have to convert the json file into a csv file.

i use the following code to conver the json file to a csv:

```
with open ("data.json", "r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
  fieldnames = data[0].keys()
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  writer.writeheader()
  for res in range(len(data)):
    writer.writerow(data[res])
```

My problem is that in the json file i have some key/value pair as i follow:

```
"title" : "Hello \n World"
```

The "\n" is taken as newline i think because it will split the row of my csv file. How solve this problem? Anyway to make my code to ignore the "\n"?

[bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLgq.png)

[output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxowV.png)

Comment: Here are some tips on adding escape to backslash special characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935754/how-to-escape-special-characters-of-a-string-with-single-backslashes

Comment: The `csv` module should handle this correctly. What is the *output you are looking for*? What is the problem?

Comment: Did you actually try it and examine your output to see the exact behavior?

Comment: My code to convert to JSON to CSV works fine if I don't have "\ n" in the whole json file. The problem is that for example if I have a json file with 2 objects, the csv file must be like 3 lines in total (1 for the header and 2 for the object). If in the json file I have the "\ n" this will divide the line in the csv file at the "\ n" thus obtaining in output a number of lines in the csv that does not represent the number of objects, because the object that contains "\ n "will be divided into two lines

Comment: I added two example images to show you the output I get and the output I would like to get

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the string.replace() method like mystring.replace('\n', ' ')?

Comment: it could be a solution, but I'm looking for something that doesn't force me to use a for loop and iterate through all my json objects to do the replace because in my final project I will have to work with millions of objects and it could be expensive to do a for loop

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` can handle this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Or since you are opening the file in Excel you could write to `xlsx` directly:

```
df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

If you still wish to remove the newlines you can use any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522652/replacing-newlines-with-spaces-for-str-columns-through-pandas-dataframe) solutions prior to saving the dataframe.